# Перебор массива начиная с определённого ключа

Tags: php, массивы

Есть две таблицы. Скрипт сначала перебирает всех пользователей, при этом у каждого пользователя в другой таблице считает кол-во рядов, всё это запихал в массив пользователь =>кол-во рядов. Всё это отсортировал и начал перебирать, но кол-во пользователей много и нужно сделать навигацию << 1 | 2 |3 ...>>, как сделать чтобы массив выводился по частям, то есть: url:index.php?page=1 - в браузере вывелось 10 записей, нажал далее вывелось след. 10 и т.п?

```
 - -- ---- Код-- - - --
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`login`,`sex` FROM `users`") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `book` WHERE `user`='".$row['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
     $i++;
     $user[$row['login']] = $rows;
    }
    arsort($user);
    foreach($user as $login => $value){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login'") or die(mysql_error());
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo '<p><a href="?users&id='.$myrow['id'].'">'.$login.'</a> <span class="small">('.$value.')</span>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы разбить массив на части используйте **[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)**. Третий параметр функции установите `TRUE`. Этот метод подойдёт если вы реализуете пагинацию на клиентской части (на JS)

---

В случае с `GET` параметром лучше редактировать сам `SQL` запрос высчитывая значение `LIMIT`.

```
LIMIT $from, $how_many
LIMIT 40, 10 // Выбрать 10 записей начиная с 40й
```

Лимит задаётся в конце запроса